# Exclude rows that contain partial data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause

I have a field in my dataset that has rows that need to excluded from my output that have the word "invalid" in the field.  The data is as follows:

```
100 - 100 - 100
100 - invalid - 300
200 - 100 - 100
200 - invalid - 500
```

How do I create a where clause that will exclude anything that contains invalid?  As a Tableau user they have a "contains" function and I'm looking for similar functionality in bigquery as a new user.

Comment: where not lower(col) like '%invalid%'

Comment: where not regexp_contains(col, 'invalid')

Comment: Hi @DayWalker,did the above comment help you?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
where not lower(col) like '%invalid%'
```